# how to call HTML into PHP in a wordpress site?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am creating a wordpress site.
My client asks me to do the coding in whole php.
But sometimes, somewhere could not use the php.
I combine the php into HTML

eg:

```
<a class="single_post_title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<h1 class="single_post_heading heading_blog"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</a>
```

if I use

```
<?php
  echo '<a class="single_post_title" href="'.the_permalink().'" title="'.the_title().'">
       <h1 class="single_post_heading heading_blog">'.the_title().'</h1>
       </a>';
?>
```

then the word press site shows `<a class="single_post_title" href="" title="">` while I inspect it using fire bug. 
the href and title attributes are empty .
might be the reason is for that wordpress built in function `the_permalink()` echoing the link already. so when I use `href="'.the_permalink().'"` the link is echoed double time in to the href attribute.

How can I over come this using PHP and calling those HTML lines into PHP?

Comment: question edited with more details... can guys go through please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
<?php  echo '<a class="single_post_title" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">
             <h1 class="single_post_heading heading_blog">'.get_the_title().'</h1>
             </a>';
```

?>

Comment: thanks for that. but the out put is **http://www.mysite.com/blog/is-it-important-to-keep-up-with-the-website-trends-in-2013/Is it important to keep up with the website trends in 2013?Is it important to keep up with the website trends in 2013? - See more at: http://www.mysite.com/blog/is-it-important-to-keep-up-with-the-website-trends-in-2013/** means anchor tag HREF is not working.  it's  just showing the link of the post

Comment: Erm, if you want to return the title instead of directly printing it use `get_the_title()` not `the_title()`. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

Same goes for `the_permalink()`. Use `get_permalink()` instead. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

Answer (score 1):

you can add html into php as:

```
<?php
echo '<a class="single_post_title" href="'.the_permalink().'"  title="'.the_title().'">';
?>
```

Comment: sorry I've commented here mistakenly.. for wordpress needs to use `get_the_permalink()` to achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
<?php
  echo '<a class="single_post_title" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">
       <h1 class="single_post_heading heading_blog">'.get_the_title().'</h1>
       </a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  echo '<a class="single_post_title" href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.get_the_title().'">
             <h1 class="single_post_heading heading_blog">'.get_the_title().'</h1>
            </a>'; 
?>
```

[image]